# How to create xap file not exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My program automatically generates an `appsturio.exe` file but I need to be `.xap`.

[image: file name output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXE is a binary executable.

XAP is an XML-based declarative framework for installing Ajax web applications.

You can't covert between the two you would have to decomplie the EXE and then rewrite it as a Ajax application.